# Url Scheme intent not working with get parameters

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, url-scheme, chrome-custom-tabs

I'm currently developing an authentication app based on OpenId Connect and Chrome CustomTabs. During the authentication flow, the user is sent to a redirection URL and I'm encountering some issues here.

In my app I have have the following intent-filter :

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="sncfapp" android:host="callbackrurl" />
</intent-filter>
```

However, the intent doesn't work sometimes. It seems that everytime the caracter "&" is used in the URL, the intent is not triggered. I get an ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME.

I tried to start launch a few URL through adb (with another receiver too) and here are my results:

**OK**          adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "fitbittester://logincallback"

**OK**          adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "sncfapp://callbackrurl"

**OK**          adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d 
"sncfapp://callbackrurl?code=45644546"

**NOK**      adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "sncfapp://callbackrurl?code=45644546&scope=test%20"

**OK**          adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "sncfapp://callbackrurl?scope=test%20"

**OK**          adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "fitbittester://logincallback?scope=test%20"

**NOK**      adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "fitbittester://logincallback?scope=test%20& code=1144"

Is it normal ? I know that such intents are supposed supposed to be used with REST parameters. However it seems weird that intents are not triggered when a URL with get parameters is called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the solution I found: I had to use the escape character "\" to use the & character with ADB.

> $ adb shell am start "http://www.example.com?param1=1\&param2=2"

Answer (score 0):

Use Url Encoding as i can see there is a space after "&"  occurrence which is causing this issue !!

Comment: Well this is not my issue. The intent-filter is not even triggered because of the "&" caracter. I don't really mind right know if i new activity is stacked on top of another.